# Having check boxes display certain things?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Got absolutely no idea how to do this or where to start. I'd like to use jQuery for it however.

I want to have a list of about 300 items. Each item is assigned from one to several different categories.

E.g:

**Items:**

Bananas,
Oranges,
Cheese,
Cake

**Categories**

Fruit,
Yellow,
Brown,
Orange,
Dessert

**The items would be assigned like following:**

Bananas - Yellow, Fruit

Oranges - Orange, Fruit

Cheese - Yellow

Cake - Brown, Dessert

.

I need to be able to tick any combination of checkboxes - e.g. If I ticked 'yellow and fruit' it would show oranges, bananas and cheese. (Notice I need all things yellow plus all things fruit, not exclusive only yellow fruits). Or If I ticked only yellow it would show cheese and bananas. If I ticked dessert and orange it would show cake and oranges. Hopefully you can understand what I mean.

I'd really appreciate any insight or help onto how this can be made possible, thanks.

Comment: To get a significative answer, show the HTML structure which whill support this.

Comment: Why not show us what you have so far "i need this" and "I need that" makes me think of being at work, without a paycheck....

Comment: I'm more looking to be pointed in the right direction because I don't even know how to approach this. I'm not even certain on what language this is possible in or anything like that.

Comment: I understand what you are saying though I don't think what I have so far will contribute at all to this problem

Comment: You may need a backend + frontend, by backend it may be php, asp.net...etc to get data from database(mysql, postgre...etc). By frontend usually it will be javascript (maybe with frameworks or library like jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matt B. Since you are new to web development let me tell you a solution which i think might be best for you from my experience so here it is. You're new in web development so i will recommend you to not use MySql as database now and PHP as logic base ... So i think you have to focus on HTML, CSS & JS for now let me guide you what you can do to achive that goal and the points are...
1. Create an html file with structure like this

```
<input class="yFruit" type="checkbox" value="YellowFruit"> Yellow Fruit<br>
<input class="rFruit" type="checkbox" value="RedFruit"> Red Fruit<br>
<div class="itemsContainer">
    <div class="item" data-category="YellowFruit"> Banana </div>
    <div class="item" data-category="RedFruit"> Apple </div>
</div>
```

2. Use Css to style these elements as you like
3. Now it's time for Javascript

You know javascripts events are very helpfull in this case like when i click on something i can detect what elemenet was that i clicked on. So same like that when we select one of those checkbox we created with html we can see what value it is got to match with all the elements(in this case all fruits with class="item") and we can add css properties to each item also like if we wanna hide some element we can do that also now lets see the code.

```
// JS Code
// assigning all the checkbox in variables
var yFruit = document.querySelector(".yFruit");
var rFruit = document.querySelector(".rFruit");
// allItems is an array containing all the item elements in it
var allItems= document.querySelectorAll(".item");

// creating a function to only show the yFruit
 function showYFruitOnly(){
    for (i = 0; i < allItems.length; i++) {
        if(allItems[i].getAttribute("data-category") == "YellowFruit"){
            // display only if it is from yellow fruit category
            allItem[i].style.display = "block";
        }else{
            // do not display if it is not from that category  
            allItem[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
 }

// code below this line is checking if yFruit is checked or not 
//every time some one clicks on it
// if it is checked then the code is running
yFruit.onchange = function(){
if(yFruit.checked == true){
    // running the showYFruitOnly function if checkbox is checked
    showYFruitOnly;
}
}
```

You can create more fuctions for more cases etc etc etc Try this and i bet you'll learn alot doing this....

Answer (score 3):

I would make an array of objects where each object has a `name` property and an `categories` attribute that is an array of strings where each string is a category name that the object falls into. Then, you can check which category checkboxes are checked, and then loop through all of the objects, only displaying the ones that have all of the selected categories in their 'categories' property. You could display them by creating elements with a loop that have the properties of the objects selected. You could find the right objects using `for` loops within `for` loops something like this:

Pseudocode:

```
//loop through the array of objects
//    for ever element, loop through its `categories` property and check if
//    it has the current element in the array of selected categories 
//    (`selected`). Then, do that for every element in `selected`
```

I know that might seem confusing, and I apologize if it is, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate it. Do you know what language would be best fit for this? Will I need PHP or something? .Net this would be a breeze though I'm still learning webdev - currently only know basics of css and html. Note that this is done on a site

Comment: I wrote this for javascript, however it only uses basic concepts so you could do this in anything you want. However, it would probably be easiest to use javascript/jQuery.

Comment: I could design some code if you like to show you what I mean.

Comment: I know everybody here doesn't expect you to go such lengths out of your way just to help. Though I really appreciate you helping me, Kai. If you do end up designing any code then I can only say thank you so, so much.